# Unable to find an inherited method for function 'dbWriteTable'

Tags: sql, r, csv, amazon-redshift, rstudio

The error is in the last line of code. I have tried multiple ways of doing it. converted data to data.frame too, but that doesn't seems to be working either. Any help would be appreciated.

```
**Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dbWriteTable’ for signature ‘"PostgreSQLConnection", "character", "missing"’**
```

```
#############Import required libraries#############
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(stringr)
library(openxlsx)
library(RPostgreSQL)


#################### Clear environment & set Working Directory #################
#rm(list=ls())

setwd(dirname(rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()$path))

data <- read.csv("Input Files/new_customer_3_24.csv")

# Convert site# and customer# columns to numeric
data$site.ID <- sprintf("%03d", data$site.ID)
data$customer.ID <- sprintf("%06d", data$customer.ID)

# Create co_cust_no by concatenating values from two columns
co_cust_no <- paste0(format(data$site.ID, format = "000"), "-", format(data$customer.ID, format = "000000"))

# Add the new column to the data 
data <- cbind(data, co_cust_no)

# Subset the data frame to keep only co_cust_no
data <- data[, c("co_cust_no")]
data <- as.data.frame(data)


# Open connection to using credentials in excel file. 
myconn <-dbConnect(dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
                   , read.xlsx("~/sqlp.xlsx", colNames = F)[5,7]
                   , port=read.xlsx("~/sqlp.xlsx", colNames = F)[6,7]
                   , dbname=read.xlsx("~/sqlp.xlsx", colNames = F)[2,7]
                   , user=read.xlsx("~/sqlp.xlsx", colNames = F)[3,7]
                   , password=read.xlsx("~/sqlp.xlsx", colNames = F)[4,7])

#Create a tmp table with co_cust_no
dbSendQuery(myconn, "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE hisp (co_cust_no varchar(50))")
dbWriteTable(myconn, name = "hisp", values = data, temporary = TRUE, overwrite = TRUE)
```

Comment: What does `methods(dbWriteTable)` return for you? Can you show `sessionInfo()` to see which versions of all these packages you are using?

Comment: I always use `library(DBI)` *in place of* `library(drivernamehere)` (your `RPostgreSQL`), and I never have problems. I recognize that many/most of the driver packages tend to facilitate loading just that package, but it's not always perfect. Use `DBI`.